# Не могу установить телеграм бот на сервере ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, telebot

Не получается задеплоить `телеграм бот` на `Ubuntu 18.04`
Все делал по этой инструкций:[инструкция](https://pastebin.com/Lsdh98FG)

Зависимости:

```
firebase==3.0.1
firebase-admin==4.3.0
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.1
grpcio==1.29.0
requests==2.23.0
```

Это я установил на сам сервер:

```
build-essential
libssl-dev
libffi-dev
python3-pip
python3-dev
python3-setuptools
python3-venv
```

После установки виртуального окружения я пошел на /etc/systemd/system/ и сделал сервис uba.service

**uba.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uba
After=network.target

[Service]
User=uba
Group=uba

WorkingDirectory=/home/kokoto/uba/
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/home/kokoto/uba/"
ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

После запуска вылетает такая ошибка:

```
uba.service - uba
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uba.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-09-21 17:48:05 MSK; 16h ago
Process: 10282 ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)
Main PID: 10282 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)

Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[1]: Started uba.
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[10282]: uba.service: Failed to determine group credentials: No such process
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[10282]: uba.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python: No such process
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[1]: uba.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
Sep 21 17:48:05 s307229 systemd[1]: uba.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Это не "такая ошибка", а какая-то ошибка. Покажите детали, например через `sudo journalctl -b -u uba.service`. Скорее всего косяк в путях/правах.

Comment: @AivanF. https://imgur.com/a/fMaPxuT вот что вышло после команды

Comment: Ну и вот, что я и говорил. Проверяйте пути и доступы, а также учитесь смотреть в логи.